# Align select, input, submit in same row without falling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in my website, I have a search box, select box and a button arranged in same row,I have fixed a width to select option to some pixel, also I have given width of textfield in to 80%, and the remining space given to the submit button, but the issue is whenever a large text comes in select option, the textfield falls to down, what i need it has to arrange width of text field automatically by the size of select box, I am fiddling my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamshajeer/a75bxhxa/)

```
<div class="my-search">
    <select>
        <option>All</option>
        <option>All</option>
        <option>All</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="seacrh-input" />
    <input type="button" value="oke" class="input-btn" />
</div>
```

**css**

```
.my-search {
    width:250px;
    background:red;
}
select, input {
    float:left;
}
input[type="text"] {
    width:60%;
}
```

and this fiddle is working fine, but for the same thing I have changed the value of select option, then the select box size is increased and the layout failed, is there any way to show this in proper ?

check the second fiddle, which having issue [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamshajeer/25kvqzf8/)

***I need a search box like www.amazon.in***

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this?

```
.my-search {
    width:250px;
    background:red;
    display: inline;
}
select, input {
    display: inline-block;
}
input[type="text"] {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/25kvqzf8/3/

Comment: This will just make the items fit in irrespective of the outer div width. And it won't solve the actual problem. The problem mentioned can be reproduced by giving a huge text in option which will exceed the screen size.

Comment: Add `max-width` property to select and it will be limited regardless how long text in option is

Comment: @r00t this is not bad, but I want exactly like search option of www.amazon.in

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that you want to resize the select box according to the content. So I have added some jQuery to achieve this (you have tagged jQuery).

I have added a dummy span to calculate the width of the select.
For outer div

```
display:table
```

And for the select and input

```
display:table-cell
```

will provide the required effect. Here the select and input fields will resize accordingly.

Has modified the code according to the amazon.in reference. Just change the width of input according to the change in select box size.

```
input_size = total_width - (select_width + button_width)
```

Also fix a initial width for the select box.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/25kvqzf8/13/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25kvqzf8/7/)

```
.my-search {
    width:250px;
    background:red;
    display: inline;
}

select, input {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 20px;
}

select{
    width: 48px;
}
```

I'm based on user @r00t reply.

Comment: please have a look on to search box of amazon.in , it shows the select option content, the width of select is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change float: left to display: inline-block and fix the width of select :

```
<div class="my-search">
    <select>
        <option>All</option>
        <option>All</option>
        <option>All</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="seacrh-input" />
    <input type="button" value="oke" class="input-btn" />
</div>

    .my-search {
    width:250px;
    background:white;
}
select, input {
    display: inline-block;
}

select {
    max-width: 20%;
}

input[type="text"] {
    width:60%;
}
```